# Can I generate a single device tree dts file from all the files in my device kernel?

Tags: kernel, device-tree

I need to fix a driver that is using a node in the device tree, the problem is that the node and it's aliases are all over the place, separated through few different files with few overrides and it is a bit confusing to try and guess which parameters values are the final ones.

Is there a way to make the compiler create and show the final device tree that is generated before creating the blob without wasting ages on full compilation and installation?